# Can I override default.xml in app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout in Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout

I try to declare a layout in

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

but it keep getting override by default.xml set in

```
Vendor/Magento/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

do I have to declare a custom theme to override layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `Magento_Theme` in your module's `etc/module.xml` file in the `<sequence>` tag. See [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html).

Example:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Your_Module" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```